# VBA Outlook mail body does not display (probably due to table pasted into mail body via vba excel)

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm currently working on a vba excel macro that filters particular rows (based on values in one column), then copies particular columns from the filtered rows & paste them as a table into the outlook email body.
I'd like the table to be pasted after the text in the email body. However, it seems that the table is the only thing that is in the mail body & I can't put the text before the table.

Would much appreciate your advice on how to display the text in the email body before the pasted table. My current: "OutMail.Body = "The body text I want to put before the table" does not work.

EDIT 1 = adjusted according to CDP1802 + added moving rows to archive feature

Code:

```
Option Explicit Public ws As Worksheet 
Public ol As ListObject
Public olRng As Range

Sub CopyTableToEmail()
Dim olCol As Integer, datCol As Integer
Set ws = Sheets("Test1")
Set ol = ws.ListObjects("TbClient")
Set olRng = ol.Range

'remove table filters
ol.ShowAutoFilter = False
'get Valid column
olCol = ol.ListColumns("Valid").Index
'filter table
ol.Range.AutoFilter field:=olCol, Criteria1:="<0", Operator:=xlOr
'select table to copy
Set olRng = ol.Range
'create mail
Call CreateMail
'Change values on Deactivation e-mail sent column
datCol = ol.ListColumns("Deactivation e-mail sent").Index
ol.ListColumns(datCol).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = Range("H1")
'clear table filters
ol.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
'Move rows to the Archive
Call MoveRows
End Sub

Sub CreateMail()
On Error GoTo errHandler
Dim olCol As Integer, rCell As Range, addRng As Range
Dim mailBcc As String, mailCC As String
'Outlook
Dim OutApp As Object, OutInsp As Object, OutMail As Object
'Declare Word Variables

Dim oWrdDoc As Word.Document, oWdEditor As Word.Editors

Dim sText As String



'Range of mail adresses

olCol = ol.ListColumns("Requestor (email)").Index

Set addRng = ol.ListColumns(olCol).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)



'get the mail addresses

For Each rCell In addRng

    mailBcc = mailBcc & rCell.Value & ";"

    mailCC = mailCC & rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & ";"

Next rCell



' copy table colmns B,J,L

ws.Columns.Hidden = False

ws.Range("A:A,C:I,K:K,M:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

olRng.Copy



Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)



Dim signature As String

With OutMail

    .display ' or send

    signature = .body

    .cc = mailCC

    .Bcc = mailBcc

    .Subject = "Openings Tracker"

End With



' Text

sText = "Ladies and gentlemen," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf



'Get the Active Inspector

'Get the document within the inspector

Set OutInsp = OutMail.GetInspector

Set oWrdDoc = OutInsp.WordEditor

With oWrdDoc

   .Content.Delete

   .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = sText

   .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Paste

   .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = signature

End With

ws.Columns.Hidden = False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
exitRoutine:



'clear

Set OutMail = Nothing

Set OutApp = Nothing

Set ws = Nothing



Exit Sub
errHandler:



'Open immediate window to see the error

Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description

Resume exitRoutine
End Sub
Sub MoveRows()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim O As Long
A = Worksheets("Test1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
B = Worksheets("Archive").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If B = 1 Then
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Archive").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Test1").Range("O1:O" & A)
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For O = 1 To xRg.Count
If CStr(xRg(O).Value) = "OK" Then
xRg(O).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & B + 1)
xRg(O).EntireRow.Delete
If CStr(xRg(O).Value) = "OK" Then
O = O - 1
End If

    B = B + 1

End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a paragraph to the word document.

update1 - Filter table, add signature to the end.

update2 - Show only columns B J L

update3 - Added AchiveRows()

```vb
Option Explicit

Public ws As Worksheet
Public ol As ListObject
Public olRng As Range

Sub CopyTableToEmail()

   Dim olCol As Integer, datCol As Integer
  
   Set ws = Sheets("Test1")
   Set ol = ws.ListObjects("tbClient")
   Set olRng = ol.Range

   'remove table filters
   ol.ShowAutoFilter = False
  
   'get Valid column
    olCol = ol.ListColumns("Valid").Index

   'filter table
   ol.Range.AutoFilter field:=olCol, Criteria1:="<0", Operator:=xlOr
  
   'select table to copy
   Set olRng = ol.Range

   'create mail
   Call CreateMail
 
   'clear table filters
   ol.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
 
End Sub

Sub CreateMail()

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim olCol As Integer, rCell As Range, addRng As Range
    Dim mailBcc As String, mailCC As String

    ' Outlook
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutInsp As Object, OutMail As Object

    'Declare Word Variables
    Dim oWrdDoc As Word.Document, oWdEditor As Word.Editors
    Dim sText As String
    
    'Range of mail adresses
    olCol = ol.ListColumns("Requestor email").Index
    Set addRng = ol.ListColumns(olCol).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    'get the mail addresses
    For Each rCell In addRng
        mailBcc = mailBcc & rCell.Value & ";"
        mailCC = mailCC & rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & ";"
    Next rCell

    ' copy table colmns B,J,L
    ws.Columns.Hidden = False
    ws.Range("A:A,C:I,K:K,M:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    olRng.Copy
 
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    Dim signature As String
    With OutMail
        .display ' or send
        signature = .body
        .cc = mailCC
        .Bcc = mailBcc
        .Subject = "Generic Subject"
    End With

    ' Text
    sText = "The body text I want to put before the table" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    'Get the Active Inspector
    'Get the document within the inspector
    Set OutInsp = OutMail.GetInspector
    Set oWrdDoc = OutInsp.WordEditor
    With oWrdDoc
       .Content.Delete
       .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = sText
       .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Paste
       .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = signature
    End With
    ws.Columns.Hidden = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

exitRoutine:
    
    'clear
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    
errHandler:
    'Open immediate window to see the error
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Resume exitRoutine
    
End Sub

Sub ArchiveRows()
    Dim ol As ListObject, rng As Range
    Dim r As Long, olCol As Long, n As Long
    
    Set ol = Sheets("Test1").ListObjects("tbClient")
    olCol = ol.ListColumns("Valid").Index

    With ol.DataBodyRange
        For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
            If UCase(Trim(.Cells(r, olCol).Value)) = "OK" Then
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = .Rows(r)
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, .Rows(r))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        n = 0
    Else
        n = rng.Rows.Count
        With Sheets("Archive")
            rng.Copy
            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With
        End With
        rng.Rows.Delete
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    MsgBox n & " rows moved to Archive and deleted"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @CDP1802 thanks for the answer :) I've tried your code (1:1) however, I get the compile error "Next without For" for the Next rCell line. Do you know how I could solve it? I've tried adding "End With" before the line (like it was in my original code), However it seems to destroy everything. I've got the Excel comunicate that there isn't enough memory to complete this action

Comment: @@CDP1802 ok my bad, I made a typo :) Many thanks for your help. In general it works, however there are 2 minor issues:
1) The table pasted into mail is the WHOLE table1, not just the columns "B:H,M:T". I need to paste only those particular columns into mail body.
2) In the body mail, the pasted table & the text are below my mail footer. 
Do you have an idea how those 2 could be fixed?

Comment: @ Kacper Do you want to see the columns B:H,M:T or hide them, your code hides them. Move `ws.Range("B:H,M:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False` after `exitRoutine`. The signature i'm working on.

Comment: Ultimately my conception changed and I want to show only columns B, J and L. However, Moving the ws.Range("B:H,M:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False after exitRoutine froze my excel :D I'll play around with it a bit more.
Would much appreciate help with the footer as I've got no idea how to tacke it.

Comment: @Kacper see update2, I have included a possible solution for the signature but I don't have Outlook set-up to test it,

Comment: Hi @CDP1802 - it worked, you're the best! :)
Now, I've added new feature to the code - Sub MoveRows().
I wanted it to move(cut) the rows (whole row, not just the 3 filtered columns) that were put into the mail table from the original sheet (Test1) to the Archive sheet and to the first empty row of that sheet.
The mechanism is used is that if the row is put into email, the macro put the current date into "Deactivation e-mail sent" column. Then the excel function put the "OK" in the "Valid" column for the rows with the current date. 
However, it does not work - the rows are not (tbc)

Comment: (cont.) The rows are not moved to the archive. Can you spot the mistake in my code? So that it also moves the rows to the archive once the table with them is put into mail.

Comment: @Kacper You have `Worksheets("Test1")` and `Worksheets("TLO")`

Comment: ah true, that's a typo on my end. Thanks for pointing out, I edited & changed to "Test1". However, moving the rows to the archive still does not work.

Comment: @Kacper The code worked for me, remove the `On Error Resume Next` and see what error you get.

Comment: Removed it & I get no error. The rows just stay in the "Test1" sheet instead of getting moved to the "Archive" sheet & getting deleted from the Test1. Did it move the rows to the arhchive for you?

Comment: @Kacper Yes worked fine, add debug.print O,CStr(xRg(O).Value) after For O = 1 To xRg.Count and single step through with F8. Check for OK's

Comment: I've added the line you posted, removed the On Error Resume Next & stepped through with F8. When I step through with F8: it highlights the line "If CStr(xRg(O).Value) = "OK" Then" and then skips straight to "End If" leaving out the code in between .Unfortunately, the result of running a macro is still the same: In column  "Valid" the value changes for "OK" for the rows that qualifies for it. However, the rows are not moved (cut) to the "Archive" and stay in the "Test1". Do you know what might be the issue then?

Comment: @Kacper Your code is `Set xRg = Worksheets("Test1").Range("O1:O" & A)`. Do you have the OK's in Column O ?

Comment: That was it! I've got OKs in the M column. Adjusted it and its works now :) Mamy thanks again @CDP1802 !

Comment: Btw. Now I'm working on formatting the email text. However the standart HTML tagging does not work when i put it into sText. From what I've read it's probably due to lack of .HTMLBody in the code. I've treid to put it instead of .body but then it destroyed all the code XD Do you have an idea how I could format the text, so that I can add line breaks, colouring, hyperlinks etc.?

Comment: @kacper If you create a temporary text file of the html you can use `.Paragraphs.Add.Range.InsertFile "C:\temp\tmp.htm", Link:=False, Attachment:=False`

Comment: Good idea, it worked. Thanks again! :)