# How to place content from excel above outlook signature

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am trying to automate excel content into outlook via VBA
However, the excel content keep on appearing below my outlook signature

How do I amend my codes so that the excel content will show before my signature? thank you all in advance

Below are my codes:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim outlookapp As Outlook.Application
Dim outlookmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outlookins As Outlook.Inspector

Dim OlWordDoc As Word.Document
Dim OlWordRng As Word.Range

Dim ExcelRng As Range

Set outlookapp = New Outlook.Application
Set outlookmail = outlookapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set ExcelRng = Sheet5.Range("A3:C6")

 With outlookmail

    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Display
    
    .To = "test@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "Commodity Allocation"
    .HTMLBody = "Below are the allocations" & .HTMLBody
    
    'Get the Active Inspector
    Set outlookins = .GetInspector
    
    'Get the Word Editor
    Set OlWordDoc = outlookins.WordEditor
    
    
    'Specify the Range in the Document
    Set OlWordRng = OlWordDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
        OlWordRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        
    'Insert a page break
        OlWordRng.InsertParagraph
        OlWordRng.InsertBreak
        
    'Copy the Excel Range
    ExcelRng.Copy
    
    'Paste into Word document
    OlWordRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteHTML

 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: In principle store the signature with `signature = .body` after `.Display` and add back at end with wordeditor. example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498402)